# To access Oracle doc through ajax call or some other method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cross-domain

I am working on a project which involve HTML,CSS and Javascript only and in this I have to read the content of oracle doc for some class say "StringBuffer" and pick the definition part of that particular class which is displayyed in a div with CSS class "description" and to show the content of that div in popup at client browser.

Right now I am using YQL(Yahoo Query Language) for the above mentioned task and displaying the result in popup.

**My Question is:** Is there any other good/fast/optimized way to solve my problem mentioned above?

First I tried to display the oracle doc content in an IFrame and tried to read the content from iframe but after going through some posts I came to know that is not possible

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php

Comment: @hashem Qolami is there any way to do the same using Javascript only? I don't want to use any server side technology.

Comment: Well, I'd use the YQL as it's fast enough. But you could use any other web services, or create your own.